# Formula - Cell value match results in Concat formula

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup, concatenation

I have reference column to trigger a concatenation of data in another sheet. Sample spreadsheet filled with the desired end result data is below.

[Sample Schedule spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yDeCRGUZZ58jyRpOMK7zzyZygMr6V7K8/view?usp=sharing)

Data validation list is used for Column H of *Schedule* sheet to select a talk number based on the Column A range in the *Lecture History* sheet. Once a value is selected for a cell in Column H (cell H3 for this example), I want to produce the following results:

1. Use the value in cell H3 of *Schedule* sheet to find a match in Column A of *Lecture History* sheet
2. If a match is found, using this Concatenate formula in cell B3 of the *Schedule* sheet
   **=CONCAT('Lecture History'!B2," (",'Lecture History'!A2,")")**
3. If no match is found or the cell H3 of *Schedule* sheet is blank, return a blank in cell B3 of the Schedule sheet

Any help with developing a formula that **does not use VBA** is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to this question can be found at Excel Forums, link below.

[Excel Forums:  Formula - Cell value match results in Concat formula](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1298925-formula-cell-value-match-results-in-concat-formula.html#post5242039)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. This answer becomes useless if the link breaks.  Instead, please [edit] your question to include the key points for future visitors.  Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/476162